# Conditional compilation/interpretation using m4

Tags: preprocessor, m4

I would like to use `m4` as a preprocessor for a couple of different scripting languages that lack this facility.

In particular, I need to emulate the C preprocessor (`cpp`) functionality of conditional code inclusion:

```
#if something

some
long
code
block

#else

alternate
code
block

#if something-else

do
more
stuff

#endif

#endif
```

m4's `ifelse()` does not particularly lend itself to long code blocks, so it seems I essentially need to write m4 macros to emulate this, by testing the condition and then using `divert` to include or exclude blocks as appropriate.

The tricky part will be keeping track of nesting levels; as far as I can tell, I will have to implement my own stack within m4 to do this.  This seems conceptually straightforward, and I'm sure with a day or two of hacking I can have a working system.

But it feels like reinventing the wheel — I surely can't be the first person with this need.  Existing, tested, robust solutions are surely better than whatever I can hack together as an m4 rank beginner.

Are there common m4 idioms for this?  Is there existing open-source m4 code to do this?  Poking around in search engines didn't turn up anything useful.

(Using cpp itself won't work for reasons given in cpp's own documentation: "It will choke on input which does not obey C's lexical rules."  It seems [gpp](http://files.nothingisreal.com/software/gpp/gpp.html) has this functionality out of the box, so using that might make more sense, but I prefer the ubiquity of m4 if it's not too painful to make m4 do this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking for this, and ended up writing my own. Here is a link to the code on my wiki:

http://www.eugeneweb.com/wiki/Sites/M4Macros

I defined the names without the #'s eg. IF, ELSE, ENDIF, etc... Also M4 requires parens to hold the arguments where CPP (Mostly) does not. I also added a selective invoke to protect macros with side effects from invocation in an unselected block.
Ciao.